# Python: how to use async/await without asyncio?

Tags: python, async-await

I am trying to understand how async/await works in Python. So I want to create some small demo program which uses this syntax.

The `async def f():` creates a coroutine. As I understand, coroutine is a resumable function. So, it should be able to start, than yield control (optionally with some intermediate results), then it should be possible to resume it and finally the function should return some value.

But it's not so easy even to make it run! Simple program:

```
# tstasync.py
async def f():
    print("f is running!")
    return 42

f()
```

just complains: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'f' was never awaited`.

Using `await` keyword wouldn't help:

```
File "./tstasync.py", line 6
    await f()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is because `await` can be used only inside another `async` function! So how to get started?

And then, how my async function can yield control? `yield` keyword is not allowed in async functions. It should call `await` something (another coroutine), but it wouldn't work if the other coruotine doesn't await for something else. Closed circle again.

The demo program should not use `asyncio` or any other modules/frameworks. Because async/await syntax is general python syntax, it's not part of `asyncio`, so it should be possible to understand what it does without any asyncio-magic.

Comment: You need *some* event loop to start running it, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, I don't. For example I can do `c = f(); c.send(None)` and it will run.

Comment: That's only for trivial cases though, and you're effectively being the event loop iterating once.

Comment: This is a really good question for the following reason: Python doesn't appear to work the same way as other languages which it comes to `async`. The keywords `async` and `await` are part of "standard Python" and are **not** coming from a library like `asyncio`. You can use these keywords without `import asyncio`. Other languages which have similar concepts include C++, where it is possible to explicitly dispatch some executable code in an asynchronous way using a thread or coroutine. Python doesn't work like this. It seems to "need" a runtime.